# Play 1.7.1 - JDK17 - Compiler Error : The type is already defined

Tags: java, playframework, java-17

in our project, we are still working with Play 1 (1.5) and due to several reasons we decided to "update" it to Play 1.7.1 and JDK 17.
Now since the Update, i get the following error:

```
Compilation error (In /app/modellogik/mitarbeiter/ModelLogikDn.java around line 23)
The file /app/modellogik/mitarbeiter/ModelLogikDn.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The type ModelLogikDn is already defined

play.exceptions.CompilationException: The type ModelLogikDn is already defined
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.lambda$compile$0(ApplicationCompiler.java:279) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:795) ~[org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.29.0.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processCompiledUnits(Compiler.java:639) ~[org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.29.0.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:475) ~[org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.29.0.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:426) ~[org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.29.0.jar:?]
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:313) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:438) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:480) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler.compile(GroovyTemplateCompiler.java:31) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:28) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:86) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:194) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at play.server.PlayHandler.serve500(PlayHandler.java:805) ~[play-1.7.1.jar:?]
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) ~[?:?]
08:23:52.845 [play-thread-1] ERROR play -
```

I already tried to solve this by checking our Code for double entries in function calls, classes, imports, ... like several suggestions here did, but i can't find the "error".
The Code works fine in older versions, but not in this one.
Is there maybe another solution or idea out there I can try?

Thanks in advance
Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Well, play 2.x doesn't officially support Java17, it's in experimental mode there. I bet that play 1.x don't support it even in experimental mode, so I'd recommend to downgrade Java version first. My educated guess would be to downgrade Java to version 8 and continue there.